# Redux: cannot update state after calling APIs

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to redux, trying to call APIs and pass the returned array of User objects to `state.admin.users`.

My codes:
//component

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log( 'componentWillMount()' );
    this.props.fetchAllUsers();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
        {
           this.props.users.map( function(user) {
              return <div>user.email</div> })
        }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log( 'state:' + JSON.stringify(state) );
    return  {
        users: state.admin.users
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchAllUsers})(myComponent);
```

// reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = { users:[] };

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  return { ...state, users:action.payload }; // Any problem here?
}
```

// actions

```
export function fetchAllUsers() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    axios.get(`${API_URL}/users`)
    .then(response => {
      console.log( 'response.data:' +JSON.stringify(response.data) );
      dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ALL_USERS,
        payload: response.data // Any problems here?
      });
    })
    .catch(response => dispatch(errorHandler(response.data.error)))
  }
}
```

console output

> state:{"admin":{}} bundle.js:2570:1
>
> componentWillMount() bundle.js:295:8
>
> OPTIONS  XHR http://myip:3001/api/users [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
>
> GET  XHR http://myip:3001/api/users [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 4ms]
>
> response.data:[{data removed}{data removed}{data removed}]

response.data look OK for me. but any problems in the above codes? why state.admin is empty? why `componentWillMount()` called after `mapStateToProps`?

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer should look like this:

```
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL_USERS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        users: action.payload
      });
  }
  return state;
}
```

Additionally, your snippets don't show how you've defined your root reducer. Does it have an `admin` key that points to this reducer?

Comment: it seems that `dispatch({
        type: FETCH_ALL_USERS,
        payload: response.data
      });` failed.

Comment: Try re-writing your promise code with the error case as the second argument for `then` instead of `catch`. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7617#issuecomment-247710003